# STM32 HAL, i2c slave direction change causes problems

Tags: stm32, i2c

**What I want to do:**

- Master writing to slave STM32F0: slave should always listen for incoming data and "always" put it to pre-configured memory location

  `HAL_I2C_Slave_Receive_IT(&hi2c1, inBuffer, size_of_buffer);`
- Master reading from STM32F0 slave: should always listen for data request and "always" read a pre-configured memory location and transfer it to master.

  `HAL_I2C_Slave_Transmit_IT(&hi2c1, outBuffer, size_of_buffer);`
- The operation of both cases is independent and overrun is not a problem

**The problem is that they work alone, but won't work together. So How should I use them?**

**What I tried with no success:**

- Call those 2 function from beginning, and recall them again in their respective TX/RX_completed callbacks.
- Periodically call them in the loop so the device is always updated with memory locations

What I believe would be related:
There are 2 functions called `HAL_I2C_Slave_Seq_Receive_IT` (see that "seq" coming in the name of the function) which takes one more parameter than normal ones calle XferOptions:

`HAL_StatusTypeDef HAL_I2C_Slave_Seq_Receive_IT(I2C_HandleTypeDef *hi2c, uint8_t *pData, uint16_t Size, uint32_t XferOptions)`

and here are the "XferOptions" for IT based operation of I2C (sorry for this long part but it's not code, it's just comments):

```
*** Interrupt mode or DMA mode IO sequential operation ***
    ==========================================================
    [..]
      (@) These interfaces allow to manage a sequential transfer with a repeated start condition
          when a direction change during transfer
    [..]
      (+) A specific option field manage the different steps of a sequential transfer
      (+) Option field values are defined through I2C_XFEROPTIONS and are listed below:
      (++) I2C_FIRST_AND_LAST_FRAME: No sequential usage, functional is same as associated interfaces in
           no sequential mode
      (++) I2C_FIRST_FRAME: Sequential usage, this option allow to manage a sequence with start condition, address
                            and data to transfer without a final stop condition
      (++) I2C_FIRST_AND_NEXT_FRAME: Sequential usage (Master only), this option allow to manage a sequence with
                            start condition, address and data to transfer without a final stop condition,
                            an then permit a call the same master sequential interface several times
                            (like HAL_I2C_Master_Seq_Transmit_IT() then HAL_I2C_Master_Seq_Transmit_IT()
                            or HAL_I2C_Master_Seq_Transmit_DMA() then HAL_I2C_Master_Seq_Transmit_DMA())
      (++) I2C_NEXT_FRAME: Sequential usage, this option allow to manage a sequence with a restart condition, address
                            and with new data to transfer if the direction change or manage only the new data to
                            transfer
                            if no direction change and without a final stop condition in both cases
      (++) I2C_LAST_FRAME: Sequential usage, this option allow to manage a sequance with a restart condition, address
                            and with new data to transfer if the direction change or manage only the new data to
                            transfer
                            if no direction change and with a final stop condition in both cases
      (++) I2C_LAST_FRAME_NO_STOP: Sequential usage (Master only), this option allow to manage a restart condition
                            after several call of the same master sequential interface several times
                            (link with option I2C_FIRST_AND_NEXT_FRAME).
                            Usage can, transfer several bytes one by one using
                              HAL_I2C_Master_Seq_Transmit_IT
                              or HAL_I2C_Master_Seq_Receive_IT
                              or HAL_I2C_Master_Seq_Transmit_DMA
                              or HAL_I2C_Master_Seq_Receive_DMA
                              with option I2C_FIRST_AND_NEXT_FRAME then I2C_NEXT_FRAME.
                             Then usage of this option I2C_LAST_FRAME_NO_STOP at the last Transmit or
                              Receive sequence permit to call the opposite interface Receive or Transmit
                              without stopping the communication and so generate a restart condition.
      (++) I2C_OTHER_FRAME: Sequential usage (Master only), this option allow to manage a restart condition after
                            each call of the same master sequential
                            interface.
                            Usage can, transfer several bytes one by one with a restart with slave address between
                            each bytes using
                              HAL_I2C_Master_Seq_Transmit_IT
                              or HAL_I2C_Master_Seq_Receive_IT
                              or HAL_I2C_Master_Seq_Transmit_DMA
                              or HAL_I2C_Master_Seq_Receive_DMA
                              with option I2C_FIRST_FRAME then I2C_OTHER_FRAME.
                            Then usage of this option I2C_OTHER_AND_LAST_FRAME at the last frame to help automatic
                            generation of STOP condition.

      (+) Different sequential I2C interfaces are listed below:
      (++) Sequential transmit in master I2C mode an amount of data in non-blocking mode using
            HAL_I2C_Master_Seq_Transmit_IT() or using HAL_I2C_Master_Seq_Transmit_DMA()
      (+++) At transmission end of current frame transfer, HAL_I2C_MasterTxCpltCallback() is executed and
            users can add their own code by customization of function pointer HAL_I2C_MasterTxCpltCallback()
      (++) Sequential receive in master I2C mode an amount of data in non-blocking mode using
            HAL_I2C_Master_Seq_Receive_IT() or using HAL_I2C_Master_Seq_Receive_DMA()
      (+++) At reception end of current frame transfer, HAL_I2C_MasterRxCpltCallback() is executed and users can
           add their own code by customization of function pointer HAL_I2C_MasterRxCpltCallback()
      (++) Abort a master IT or DMA I2C process communication with Interrupt using HAL_I2C_Master_Abort_IT()
      (+++) End of abort process, HAL_I2C_AbortCpltCallback() is executed and users can
           add their own code by customization of function pointer HAL_I2C_AbortCpltCallback()
      (++) Enable/disable the Address listen mode in slave I2C mode using HAL_I2C_EnableListen_IT()
            HAL_I2C_DisableListen_IT()
      (+++) When address slave I2C match, HAL_I2C_AddrCallback() is executed and users can
           add their own code to check the Address Match Code and the transmission direction request by master
           (Write/Read).
      (+++) At Listen mode end HAL_I2C_ListenCpltCallback() is executed and users can
          add their own code by customization of function pointer HAL_I2C_ListenCpltCallback()
      (++) Sequential transmit in slave I2C mode an amount of data in non-blocking mode using
            HAL_I2C_Slave_Seq_Transmit_IT() or using HAL_I2C_Slave_Seq_Transmit_DMA()
      (+++) At transmission end of current frame transfer, HAL_I2C_SlaveTxCpltCallback() is executed and
            users can add their own code by customization of function pointer HAL_I2C_SlaveTxCpltCallback()
      (++) Sequential receive in slave I2C mode an amount of data in non-blocking mode using
            HAL_I2C_Slave_Seq_Receive_IT() or using HAL_I2C_Slave_Seq_Receive_DMA()
      (+++) At reception end of current frame transfer, HAL_I2C_SlaveRxCpltCallback() is executed and users can
           add their own code by customization of function pointer HAL_I2C_SlaveRxCpltCallback()
      (++) In case of transfer Error, HAL_I2C_ErrorCallback() function is executed and users can
           add their own code by customization of function pointer HAL_I2C_ErrorCallback()
      (++) Discard a slave I2C process communication using __HAL_I2C_GENERATE_NACK() macro.
           This action will inform Master to generate a Stop condition to discard the communication.
```

Comment: The correct answer may just be that the HAL can't do what you want, as it's not feasible to write a HAL that can do anything anyone can ever think of. But in your case, can't the EnableListen_IT() handle that?

Comment: @Justme it's just the normal operation of an slave device that can read or write to master and I simply want that functionality. BTW I wasn't familiar with enableListen_IT, imma give it a try. thanx

Comment: Show your code!!  What are the HAL_StatusTypeDef returns (or status registers later on)? Did you measure the I2C lines on the PCB? Did you see signals? If so try to receive a byte in blocking mode, switch to _IT or _DMA functions after you got the blocking version to work.

Comment: @TirdadSadriNejad I'm currently working on solving the problem you mentioned, have you solved it yet?

Comment: @LianjiangTang unfortunately no. I'm trying to write a new interrupt-based library. Re-inventing the wheel this time is way easier than understanding their poorly documented library.